# emacs listing packages error in process sentinel

Tags: emacs, package

I'm new to `emacs`, have installed `emacs26`, and I use a proxy server. When I tried to add packages it is showing this error:

> error in process sentinel:
>
> Error retrieving: https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/archive-contents (error connection-failed "failed with code 110" :host "elpa.gnu.org" :service 443)

I added the following code:

```
(setq url-proxy-services
   '(("no_proxy" . "^\\(localhost\\|172.16.2.30\\)")
     ("http" . "localhost:8080")
     ("https" . "localhost:8080")))
```

But I still get the same error.

Comment: You don't show any code that makes use of GNU ELPA repository or package `archive-contents`. Please provide a recipe to reproduce the problem, starting with `emacs -Q` (no init file).

Answer (score 13):

It appears that

```lisp
(custom-set-variables
 '(gnutls-algorithm-priority "normal:-vers-tls1.3"))
```

fixes the problem.

Cf. https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/56067/795